# Какая стандартная длина (высота) отступа br в пикселях?

Tags: html

То есть на сколько он отступает, зависит ли это от браузера.
И тоже самое с <p></p>

Comment: Он не отступает, а создаёт перенос строки. А высота строк зависит от умолчаний браузера и текущих стилей

Comment: Вот меня интересует это расстояние, оно у кого какое?

Comment: А у `<p>` по умолчанию обычно стоит margin 1em, а размер этого em опять же зависит от умолчаний браузера и текущих стилей

Comment: а у  <br> какая?

Comment: @СергейРакипов, у br нет отступа, он просто делает еще одну строку, высота которой задается свойством `line-height`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете вычислить это экспериментальным путём. Взять два дива, разделить их переносом строки и высчитать получившееся расстояние:

```js
let topDiv = document.getElementById('top');
let bottomDiv = document.getElementById('bottom');
let brHeight = bottomDiv.offsetTop - topDiv.offsetTop - topDiv.offsetHeight;
console.log(brHeight)
```

```css
#top, #bottom {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<br>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: кроме css и html не чего не знаю, а что говорит этот код?

Comment: @СергейРакипов, этот код говорит, сколько в пикселях расстояние между двумя блоками

Comment: `<br/>` переносит строку, следовательно после переноса высота будет равна высоте строки, которая задается свойством `line-height`

Comment: на 5 пикселей? правильно?

Comment: @СергейРакипов, почему 5? 19 же. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код".

Comment: @СергейРакипов, но это здесь. Разумеется, в другом браузере и другой "песочнице" это значение может отличаться. Например, в jsfiddle данный код вернёт 18.

Comment: @humster_spb Хром и тут тоже возвращает 18.

Comment: @Yaant, а у меня 19 :)))

Comment: @humster_spb Любопытно. Проверил в Chrome 86.0.4240.193 / Win 7, 86.0.4240.198 / Win 10, Chrome 87.0.4280.66 / Win 10, Edge 87, Firefox 83 — Везде 18.

Comment: ...А вот если сделать масштаб страницы 110% — тогда 19 :)

Comment: @Yaant, точно, у меня масштаб был 110% =)))